# How to include the QtCharts library in Qt Creator 4.2.0 (Community)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts

[image]

I tried to include the QtCharts but i have an error when i include the library, this is the error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts.

I have included the QT += charts in the *.pro file like this:

```
QT += charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += charts

SOURCES += \
    source.cpp
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: please, show complete .pro

Comment: Use QT       += core gui charts

Comment: QT       += core gui charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

Comment: It doesn't work (That's my *.pro file): QT += core gui charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    source.cpp

Comment: What version of Qt do you have?

Comment: Qt Creator 4.2.0 (4.2.0)
Based on Qt 5.7.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)

Built on Dec 9 2016 12:30:00

From revision 5071dd80cb

Copyright 2008-2016 The Qt Company Ltd. All rights reserve

Comment: press Build > Run Qmake

Comment: Still send me an error with this in the .pro:                                                   QT += core gui charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    source.cpp
And in the .cpp file:                                                                                       #include <iostream>
#include <QtCharts>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Comment: The error is this: -1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts

Comment: When you installed it, did you enable that module?

Comment: i don't remember, so how can i add that module if that is the problem or where can i find if the module is installed?

Comment: See my solution

Comment: I would recommend reinstalling by enabling Qt Charts

Comment: :( i'll do it ,thanks

Comment: If my answer will help you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the installation process you must enable `Qt Charts`. This is not enabled by default.:

[image]

Click on Qt Charts:

[image]

Comment: I've already use Qt Maintenance but the error persist, can you help?