# Qt Datavisualization is missing from qt 5.7

Tags: qt

I try to use the qt datavisualization from Qt 5.7 (since it can be used for free) but when I add in my .pro file

```
QT+=datavisualization
```

I got "Project error:unknown modules"

Is there a way to install this module manually without downloading the 5.8 version?

Comment: In the installation process you must enable this option.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625233/how-to-include-the-qtcharts-library-in-qt-creator-4-2-0-community/41625628#comment70454153_41625628

Comment: Thanks for that! it is not my computer but my university so i don't have access for any installation. Anyway i will tell the admnistrator