# How to fix "QtCharts" library file not found/can't include <QtCharts>?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm new to Qt GUI/Widget Application and I am trying to make a simple bar chart. I tried to copy the exact same code that QT provides in their website, [link]: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtcharts-barchart-example.html#creating-bar-charts. However, I keep getting a lot of error message that says "QtCharts" file not found and "QBarSet" "QLegend" not found, basically every library that was included was not found.

I saw some troubleshoot page in QT website, it says that I have to add some import statement in my .qml file. But I can't seem to find where is the .qml file located? [link]: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html

My code looks exactly like this:

```
//main.cpp
----------
[link]: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtcharts-barchart-main-cpp.html
```

```
//.pro file
------------
QT       += core gui charts
//I only add "charts" in the above line from the original .pro file
//everything else is the exact same .pro file as in the original.

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testing_file
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

How do you fix/make the code works? I really have no idea how to fix the error messages. Thanks!

Comment: How have you installed Qt?

Comment: Well of course. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Qt has many ways to install, if you have used the online installer you must enable the submodule Qt Charts because by default it is disabled so that submodule is not installed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625233 . If you have used another form you must indicate it.

Comment: I see. I kind of forgot how do I installed my QT, but if I'm not mistaken I just enabled the default submodule that the QT offers. However, how do you enable/add the submodule QT Charts if you already installed the QT?

Comment: If you installed with the online installer then just run that installer and run that submodule as if you installed it back. If you have used another method then you must point it out since the previous method will not be the solution.

Comment: Resolved! I just reinstalled the qt and enabled the Qt Charts module and it works! Thank you eyllanesc!

Answer (score 2):

I just realized I did not install the components/submodule of QT Charts, as mentioned by eyllanesc. I had to reinstall the QT all over again and enable the QT Charts components. You can add it with QT Maintenence tool but I didn't have it so I just reinstall it again because I still got the installer.

Reference: [How to include the QtCharts library in Qt Creator 4.2.0 (Community)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41625233)

Comment: I've already use Qt Maintenance but the error persist, can you help?